# Binary Coding in Long Format in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data has respondents (10 in this example) that choose between n choices (3 in this example).

```
# original data
df <- data_frame(RID = seq(1:10), choice = sample(1:3,10,replace = TRUE))
```

I am trying to code this as a binary value, but in long (tidy) format using `dplyr`. My spidey sense is telling me there is probably a better way than using a `spread` and `gather` together.

```
# desired output
df %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  spread(choice,value, fill=0) %>%
  gather("choice","selection",2:4) %>%
  arrange(RID,choice)
```

Any thoughts on a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tidyr::complete` to create all combinations of unique values from columns (here you need `RID` and `choice`):

```
df %>% 
    mutate(selection = 1) %>%                         # create a selection column of 1
    complete(RID, choice, fill = list(selection = 0)) # fill selection with 0 for missing combinations

# A tibble: 30 x 3
#     RID choice selection
#   <int>  <int>     <dbl>
# 1     1      1        1.
# 2     1      2        0.
# 3     1      3        0.
# 4     2      1        0.
# 5     2      2        0.
# 6     2      3        1.
# 7     3      1        0.
# 8     3      2        0.
# 9     3      3        1.
#10     4      1        1.
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be using `expand.grid` as:

```
#Create all possible combination using RID and unique choice
result <- expand.grid(RID = df$RID, choice = unique(df$choice))

#New column as 'select' will be 1 for those combination which were present in original df
result$selection = ifelse(result$RID == df$RID & result$choice == df$choice, 1, 0)

result

#1    1      2         1
#2    2      2         0
#3    3      2         0
#4    4      2         0
#5    5      2         0
#6    6      2         0
#7    7      2         0
#8    8      2         0
#9    9      2         1
#........
#........
#30 rows
```